# getting mongoose save error null while enter duplicate data on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hi please help me to solve code i have userSchema and username and password are unique. when i enter duplicate data on MongoDB data save successfully.and i want to get error when i am putting a duplicate data in the MongoDB.

```
//UserSchema

var userSchema =mongoose.Schema({
    user:{type:String,require:true,unique:true},
    pass:{type:String,require:true,unique:true}
})


router.post('/users',function(req,res){    
    var newUser = new Item.user({
        user:req.body.username,
        pass:req.body.password
    });        
    if(req.body.username ==null || req.body.username=='' || req.body.password ==null || req.body.password=='' ){            
        res.json({success : false, message : 'Ensure username ,email and password provided'});
    }else{
        newUser.save(function(err){
            console.log('save errror ',err);
            if(err){                     
                res.json({success : false , message :'user already exist' });
            }
            else{                    
                res.json({success :true , message : 'successfully saved'});
            }
        });

    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal working example of the code that doing what you want.
Please take a look how the error is handled. So it's possible to separate duplicate key error from any other errors.

I used to use `express`, `body-parser` and `mongoose` to make it work. Also refactored your code a bit. Hope this helps.

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {type: String, require: true, unique: true},
    pass: {type: String, require: true, unique: true}
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/users', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
        res.json({success: false, message: 'Ensure username, email and password provided'});
        return;
    }

    const newUser = new User({
        user: req.body.username,
        pass: req.body.password
    });

    newUser.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('save errror ', err);

            if (err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 11000) {
                // Duplicate error happened. You can handle it separately.
                res.json({success: false, message: 'user already exist'});
                return;
            }

            // Some other error happened, you might also want to handle it.
            res.json({success: false, message: 'some error happened'});
            return;
        }

        res.json({success: true, message: 'successfully saved'});
    });
});

app.listen(8888);
```

Comment: but i getting err is null then how can i check a condition              console.log('save error ',err);

Comment: If the err is null that means that the .save() was executed successfully. In this case res.json({success: true ...) is going to be called. See the if (err) statement and the return's. @MohammadFaisal

Comment: yes .save() is executed successfully but the duplicate data is stored in the database and i don't want to store duplicate data in a database

Comment: If you are passing the username and password which are unique - they are saved to the database. If you're trying to save the duplicated - it's going to throw the MongoError with the code 1100 and DOESN'T save it. I just tested. @MohammadFaisal

Comment: Try dropping your database and test it again. Maybe the indexes somehow were not created @MohammadFaisal